# Multithreading not supported in MI devices for android app

Tags: java, android, multithreading

We are building android app using multi threading as its working on almost all device except MI and few other devices that not supported Multi threading.

Try to call recording service in background using new threads. for that we create stopRecording() function that will call in new threads and its work in all device well but only few device like MI not working as we assumed there are not multi thread support in these devices   ?

we are using below code

```
if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state)&&recording==true)
{
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//Toast.makeText(arg0, "STOP Called :"+recording, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

stopRecording();

}

public void stopRecording()
{
if(recording==true)
{
try
{
te = getCurrentTS();
recorder.stop();
recorder.reset();
recorder.release();
recorder=null;
recording=false;

editor.putString("mdialerRecording", "false");editor.commit();

//broadcastIntent();
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recorder_Relesed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

File oldfile = new File(fname);
byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) oldfile.length()];
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(oldfile));
dis.readFully(fileData);
dis.close();

oldfile.delete();

try
{
String s64mp3file=Base64.encodeToString(fileData,Base64.NO_WRAP);

String newKey=calledCRM+"_"+sysNumber+"_"+ts+"_"+te;
editor.putString(newKey, s64mp3file);

String mdialerKeys=settings.getString("mdialerKeys", "");
editor.putString("mdialerKeys", mdialerKeys+"|"+newKey);

editor.commit();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File_EX "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

calledCRM="";
if(calledNum.equals(sysNumber))deleteLogNumber(sysNumber);
calledNum="";
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rec_Stop_EX "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
}
```

Comment: "we assumed there are not multi thread support in these devices ?" -- threads work just fine in Xiaomi devices. "only few device like MI not working" -- you will have better luck if you explain, in detail, what "not working" means.

Comment: how you creating and run new thread ?

Comment: You are wrong saying Mi devices not support multithreading.

Comment: I am asking not telling ,  this one is multi threading not supported issue or some thing else as in MI device our app get  android not responding because main thread blocked where its working fine in all other devices

Comment: maybe the problem it's not the multi threading, the code you posted is really not clear

Comment: Where is your multithread code ? From the above example you just show some code that we have to assume is called on a thread. We can't help you if you don't post relevant code.